# How should I divide clients while using Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing

I’m currently working at a software development company. And we are thinking of creating a single Kubernetes cluster where we want to host all our client projects (which are completely unrelated one with the other).

The idea is to have a namespace for each client, where we can have multiple deployments for development, staging, production, etc. inside each namespace.

Is this a bad idea and should I have a cluster for each client? Has anyone tried something like this before? How did it work out?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest separating your env by cluster at the very least.  Depending on what your budget is, maybe you want to just bucket dev & staging into a non-prod cluster, but definitely separate your production environment.

You can have your clients namespaced, but it also consider the complexity of your client projects (do you need Ingress, load balancers, PVC, PV, etc.).  If they're not that complex, then maybe something serverless (like GCP's Cloud Run for example) might be the solution for you that's both cost-effective and easy to manage...

...which leads me to my next question: are you running this in the cloud or is this to be self-managed k8s cluster?  I've worked on a self-managed k8s cluster before (this was before managed-k8s was available in Canadian regions and we had compliance reasons for keeping the cluster/data in Canada).  We had a single cluster for non-prod that was namespaced and our prod environments were 1 cluster per client.  Managing it was difficult, but we split up prod for the reason that we didn't want all our eggs in one basket for something that we realistically didn't have any official support for (outside of StackOverflow or GitHub issues).  If you're using a cloud-managed solution, I think a namespaced client project setup is doable.

Comment: The idea is to run the cluster on the cloud.

And yeah I thought of at least separating the production environment in a different cluster. But what I don't know is if I will eventually hit any limits by using namespaces, is there anything that namespaces can't isolate from the rest of the cluster?

Maybe having a cluster per client will end up being the final approach, even though it will be a pain to maintain. Or at least dedicate a cluster for clients that reach a certain usage/project complexity.

Comment: AFAIK there's no limit on namespaces and (you'll have to confirm exact numbers with your cloud provider) can support a **lot** of nodes.  How many nodes does a client project deployment take up?   I assume you'll want that HA aspect and let's assume 2 services at 2 replicas each, that's 4 pods that you'll want to probably spread across 2-3 nodes for a client.   If they're lightweight, you can probably run a lot.  But plan ahead make sure you have sufficient IPs for nodes and pod/svc IPs as well.